# Creating a point system from a list of matches

Tags: python

I have a list that takes in analysis x matches of a tournament, each match is divided in y sections. Each number of the list tells me if the section was won, lost or draw (1, -1, 0).
Every team has to play against every other team only once, so if I have 3 teams the list will look like this: index 0 = player 1 vs player 2, index 1 = player 1 vs player 3 and index 2 = player 2 vs player 3.
For example here's a list:

```
matches = [[1,0,0], [1,1,-1], [0,0,1]]
```

So in matches[0] player one won one section and drew two (meaning that player 2 lost), in matches[1] player 1 won two sections and lost one (meaning that player 3 lost) and in matches[2] player 2 won one section and drew two (meaning that player 3 lost).
From this I should come with some points to assign to each team, 2 if the match was won, 1 for a draw and 0 for a loss.
In this situation the expected output would be

```
[4, 2, 0]
```

I tried many solutions but never got to the expected output. If someone could help me out I would really appreciate it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your point system is a bit complicated, but you can try something like that:

```
matches = [[1,0,0], [1,1,-1], [0,0,1]]


def calculate_match(match: list, pos: bool): # pos = True if player goes first (player1 is first in p1 vs p2 match), False if player goes second
    return (2 if (sum(match) > 0 if pos else sum(match) < 0) else 1 if sum(match) == 0 else 0)


p1 = calculate_match(matches[0], True) + calculate_match(matches[1], True)
p2 = calculate_match(matches[0], False) + calculate_match(matches[2], True)
p3 = calculate_match(matches[1], False) + calculate_match(matches[2], False)

print(p1, p2, p3)
```

Output:

```
>>> 4 2 0
```

Comment: that one liner is hard to read

Comment: Thank you because it worked but I have no idea of what I wrote lmao